# Overloaded member function not found

Tags: c++

I have a problem with my code, the error is:

```
    1>c:\users\grother\documents\obiektowe\lab05_195975\lab05_195975\czlowiek.cpp(6): error C2511: 'czlowiek::czlowiek(void)' : overloaded member function not found in 'czlowiek'
    1>c:\users\grother\documents\obiektowe\lab05_195975\lab05_195975\czlowiek.h(3) : see declaration of 'czlowiek'
```

This is `czlowiek.h`

```
class czlowiek      
{
    private:

    public: 
        int wiek, pola, r;
        char plec, *p, imie[15], nazwisko[25];
        static int n;
        string ulubioneKsiazki;

        //czlowiek();
        virtual ~czlowiek();
        czlowiek(const string& ulubioneKsiazki="Brak informacji")
        {
            this->ulubioneKsiazki=ulubioneKsiazki;
        };
};
```

and this is `czlowiek.cpp`:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "czlowiek.h"

int czlowiek::n=0;

czlowiek::czlowiek():p(0)
{
    n++;
}

czlowiek::~czlowiek()
{
    n--;
}
```

I've tried changing the constructor, but I have no idea how to make this one work.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Where did you declare `czlowiek()` in the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the definition of the default constructor from your `.cpp` file, since you have a single parameter constructor with a default parameter:

```
czlowiek(const string& ulubioneKsiazki="Brak informacji")
{
    this->ulubioneKsiazki=ulubioneKsiazki;
};
```

This acts as a default constructor, since it can be invoked without arguments.

Another alternative is to remove the default parameter in the single parameter constructor, and add a declaration for the default constructor. For example:

```
czlowiek() : ulubioneKsiazki="Brak informacji" {}
czlowiek(const string& ulubioneKsiazki) : ulubioneKsiazki(ulubioneKsiazki) {}
```

Bear in mind that your class has quite a few other data members that should probably be initialized.

Comment: Then I get this error:

    'czlowiek' : multiple default constructors specified

that's why it's commented out :(